# UISplitViewController - How to add a view over the top?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, iad

I want to add a view controller over the top of a UISplitViewController so that I can sit a horizontal iAd iPad banner across both views in the splitview.

Is this possible? It has to be a uiviewcontroller for the ADBannerView to be happy.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is almost 2 years old, but I have found on apple examples the solution for this problem:

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Listings/SplitViewBanner_SplitViewBanner_AppDelegate_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010198-SplitViewBanner_SplitViewBanner_AppDelegate_h-DontLinkElementID_23) you can find the SplitViewBanner example that shows how to add a ADBannerView and a UISplitViewController to another view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible. This isn't the cleanest way but I have added a `view` to the `keyWindow`, like this: `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:someView];`. This guarantees that it'll be the top-most view.

Another thing to consider is changing the `frame` of the `UISplitViewController`. Make it just tall enough to fit an `ADBannerView` underneath.

Comment: The AdBanner must be part of a UIViewController. UISplitterViewControllers must be the bottom most otherwise the Delegate won't fire. So a AdBanner can not bet put below a UISplitterViewControllers unless it's in a UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I think Apple have moved all their examples to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite_Storyboard/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013458-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Also, I found this much simpler code in the AdBannerView Class Reference to deal with AdBanners that don't fit the view:

```
ADBannerView *myBannerView = <#Get a banner view#>;
UIView *myContainingView = <#Get the containing view#>;
NSSize newBannerSize = [myBannerView sizeThatFits:myContainingView];
[myBannerView setBounds:newBannerSize];
```